# How change child theme's boxed layout to fullwidth in genesis?

Tags: child-theme

I'm using LifeStyle Pro Genesis Child theme, that has a boxed layout of width=1140px. I first changed it to 1200px and worked with that layout.
Now I want to test some pages with fullwidth-layout, meaning wider than 1200px, not boxed.

In settings of the "Genesis Layout Extra Plugin" I only find 'fullwidth-content'. But using that means just not having the sidebar any more.

So: What code in what file I have to use to get a fullwidth website? Is it possible and recommended to modify a child theme that has boxed layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the same width to everything, change the `max-width` of the `.wrap`

```
.wrap {
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

If you just want to change the width of the content section, add the following code:

```
.site-inner .wrap {
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

Hope it works for you, good luck.

Comment: Only change `.wrap` doesn't modify it. But your answer reminds my that I can investigate it further by using Firebug. So I found out that it is working with 

`.site-container {max-width: 100%}`

How could I modify now the header-image, that has a width of 1200px? I will check that with Firebug too, but maybe You have a solution right now?

Comment: It's probably the `max-width` of `.header-image .site-title a`

You can also search for "1200px". Let me know if it works.

If I was able to help, I would be thankful if you would upvote and select right answer.

Comment: Not yet solved. But this is the existing code for  the fullwidth-header-background-image: 

`.header-full-width.header-image .site-title a {
 background-position: center center !important;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 290px;
}`

Just adding a line `max-width: 100%` doesn't work here. I'll give you the URL of the test-side here: [link](http://www.official.jungvital.com). You can see that the page is allready fullwidth now. Also the header. But the header-image not.

Comment: The problem is the small background image.
You can change its width by the changing the `.site-title a` to the following code:  `.site-title a {
    background-image: url(http://www.official.jungvital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Lotos-Bluete.jpg) !important;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`
But ideally, you should upload a wider image.

Comment: To upload is a wider image is indead a better solution. And what width it should have then? 1920px? What is if a visitor has a larger screen?

Comment: I found out that I have to change some settings in functions.php: `//* Add support for custom header
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
 'header_image'    => '',
 'header-selector' => '.site-title a',
 'header-text'     => false,
 'height'          => 400,
 'width'           => 1920,
 'flex-height'   => true,
) );`

And the other changes in style.css cause disappearing of the header-image when mouse is above.

Comment: Yes, 1920px width would cover all the screens you need. For the height you can use the one you have on the site  `min-height: 328px;` or play around with the ratios. If you are afraid the visitor may have a larger screen, visit [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/screen-resolution-statistics.htme) .

Comment: Good, you will be able to define and upload the size you want.

Comment: Your link (this) gives 404 Not Found. - Have you an idea about the phenomen the header-image disappears when mouse is above? I will check that too.

Comment: [Working link](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/screen-resolution-statistics.htm) - I'm not able to reproduce that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe it was some caching problem. It is OK now.